# How to run an Elixir application?

Tags: elixir

What is the correct way to run an Elixir application?

I'm creating a simple project by:

```
mix new app
```

and after that I can do:

```
mix run
```

which basically compiles my app once. So when I add:

```
IO.puts "running"
```

in `lib/app.ex` I see `"running"` only for the first time, each consecutive `run` does nothing unless there are some changes. What can I do next with generated `app.app`?

Of course I know I can do:

```
escript: [main_module: App]
```

in `mix.exs`, provide `def main(args):` and then:

```
mix escript.build
./app
```

but's it's kinda cumbersome in my opinion.

There's also something like:

```
elixir lib/app.exs
```

but it does not count `mix.exs` obviously, which is needed for dependencies in my `app`.

Comment: If you want to run an Elixir script (a `.exs` file) but do so in the context of your mix app, you can run `mix run <script>`. See `mix help run` for more information.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`mix run` does run your app. It's just that when you simply put `IO.puts "something"` in a file that line is only evaluated in compile-time, it does nothing at runtime. If you want something to get started when you start your app you need to specify that in your `mix.exs`.

Usually you want a top-level `Application` that will get started. To achieve that add a `mod` option to your `mix.exs`:

```elixir
def application do
  [
    # this is the name of any module implementing the Application behaviour
    mod: {NewMix, []},
    applications: [:logger]
  ]
end
```

And then in that module you need to implement a callback that will be called on application start:

```elixir
defmodule NewMix do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    IO.puts "starting"
    # some more stuff
  end
end
```

The `start` callback should actually setup your top-level process or supervision tree root but in this case you will already see that it is called every time you use `mix run`, although followed by an error.

```elixir
def start(_type, _args) do
  IO.puts "starting"
  Task.start(fn -> :timer.sleep(1000); IO.puts("done sleeping") end)
end
```

In this case we are starting a simple process in our callback that just sleeps for one second and then outputs something - this is enough to satisfy the API of the `start` callback but we don't see `"done sleeping"`. The reason for this is that by default `mix run` will exit once that callback has finished executing. In order for that not to happen you need to use `mix run --no-halt` - in this case the VM will not be stopped.

Another useful way of starting your application is `iex -S mix` - this will behave in a similar way to `mix run --no-halt` but also open up an `iex` shell where you can interact with your code and your running application.

Comment: Alright, that's almost what I needed! One more thing, can you explain this `returned a bad value: :ok` error when there's not `Task`, or `Agent` or `Supervisor` etc.? How does that work and why do we need a separate process? Why can't I just run some script that executes whatever I need?

Comment: An application callback must return a supervision tree. If you don't return one, it will fail. In fact, I would even replace the last expression shown by Paweł by: `Supervisor.start_link [], strategy: :one_for_one`. Returning a task that shuts down may cause the application to fail after sleeping.

Comment: @squixy some of the benefits of using and defining applications are outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422184/where-does-elixir-erlang-fit-into-the-microservices-approach/30423183#30423183

Comment: So the last question is: is it better to use `Task.start(my_other_method)` or run `my_other_method` and then `Supervisor`?

Comment: If you're building any kind of long-running application you almost always want a `Supervisor`. I used a `Task` just to have the smallest correct program but as Jose mentioned - you want to start your supervision tree there.

Comment: Great answer! One question though. You wrote _"It's just that when you just put `IO.puts "something"` in a file that line is only evaluated in compile-time, it does nothing at runtime."_ which seems to corresponds to what I'm seeing but I don't understand the logic of this? Why does it work that way?

Comment: Being able to run Elixir code at compile time allows you to metaprogram easily. The knack is knowing which parts are executed during compilation and which ones make it into the compiled program.

Comment: Ah, right, sounds really interesting. Is there some documentation on how this works? Which parts that are executed during compilation and so on? I tried googling but I didn't find anything that talked specifically about that.

Comment: You might try to read up on macros and code generation - that should give you a better intuition of what is happening when. You might also look into how Elixir implements unicode handling: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/unicode/unicode.ex - it's a great practical example.

Answer (score 14):

You can run tasks by importing `Mix.Task` into your module instead of `mix run`.

I think [this](http://joeyates.info/2015/07/25/create-a-mix-task-for-an-elixir-project/) is what you're looking for.

On top of that, instead of `mix <task.run>`, you can simply run `mix` to run the default task. Simply add `default_task: "bot.run"` into the list of `def project do [..] end` in `mix.exs`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073023/how-do-i-set-the-default-elixir-mix-task).